# Calculating expected value for X given a scenario

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

This question was given to me as a review for an upcoming exam:

> $12$ baseballs are dropped into $5$ empty bins. Let $X$ be the number of empty bins after dropping the balls.
>   Calculate $\langle X \rangle$ (Expected value of $X$) and $P(X=4)$ and $P(X=3)$

My work thus far:

$$\langle X \rangle = \langle X_5 \rangle + \langle X_4 \rangle + \langle X_3 \rangle + \langle X_2 \rangle + \langle X_1 \rangle  \\
\langle X \rangle = \left(\frac45 \right)^{12} \cdot (5+4+3+2+1) \approx 1.0308 \\
P(X=4)=5 \left(\frac15 \right)^{12} \approx 2.048 \cdot 10^{-8} \\
P(X=3)=\binom{5}{2} \left(\frac25 \right)^{12} \approx 0.000167 $$

Did I do anything incorrectly?

Comment: What is $<X>$ and what is $X_5$ ?

Comment: $<X>$ is the expected value of X, that is, the expected empty bins total of all 5 bins. $<X_5>$ is the expected value of the 5th bin

Comment: Not clear. " the expected value of the 5th bin" ... yo mean the expected number of balls in the 5th bin? If so, the sum would only make sense if $X$ were the total number of balls - it isn't. I cannot make sense of that.

Comment: @leonbloy: No, I think Joe means $X_5 = 1$ if the fifth bin is empty, and $0$ if it is not.  Then the sum works, by linearity of expectation, except that instead of multiplying by $5+4+3+2+1 = 15$, we should just multiply by $5$.

Comment: OP: It doesn't make sense to multiply by $5+4+3+2+1$ in your second line.  Why is $X_5$ multiplied by $5$?  There are only five boxes, and each one has a probability $(4/5)^{12}$ of being empty, so just add those up across all five boxes to find the mean number of empty boxes.

Comment: Your expression for $P(X = 3)$ includes cases where $X = 4$.